# Beginners Java (Loops) - Missing return statement

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, return-value

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vending {
    public double vend(double balance) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        balance = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a command = ");
        String command = in.nextLine();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            if (command.equals("penny")) {
                balance = balance + 0.01;
                System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
            }
            return balance;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi! I have tried everything to figure out why the return statement is not being recognized. If I put the "return balance" anywhere else it says that the system.out.println is unreachable... Can any of you kindly help me out as to why this may not be working?? Thank you!!

Comment: Your code would be *much* easier to understand - both for you and us - if you would indent it. If you're using an IDE like Eclipse, you can probably ask it to reformat your source code for you. Once you've done that, the answer may be much more obvious. (I suspect I know what's wrong already, but I want you to reformat the code and see if you can find it yourself.)

Comment: Ah, except I see it's been done already :(

Comment: I thought it was faster to indent it myself than to ask the OP to do it :)

Comment: It seems like there is a logic issue. You have to re-read the new line every loop as opposed to reading it once and expecting the loop to work as intended.

Comment: That said, accidentally I removed the actual question... Fixed now, sorry for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing return statement inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238388/missing-return-statement-inside-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 3):

The `return` statement is inside the `while` loop and outside the `if` condition segment, so the code its breaking the loop on the first iteration.

Possible solution: move the `return` outside the `while`

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    if (command.equals("penny")) {
        balance = balance + 0.01;
        System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
    }
}
return balance;
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried moving the     return outside the while but then I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:main" , when I left all else constant. Do you know what may be the problem then?

Comment: @BettyJones well, you fixed the `vend` method problem. Now, make sure you have declared the main method as `public static void main(String[] args)`. If you have a new problem, it would be better to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `vend(double balance)` is defined to return a `double`. Whatever happens within the method, it must return a double. Now you have a return statement here:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    if (command.equals("penny")) {
        balance = balance + 0.01;
        System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
    }
    return balance;
}
```

But what happens if your statement `in.hasNext()` returns `false`? Then the `return` inside it will never be reached. Therefore the compiler can not guarantee that your method is valid java and is therefore complaining.

You should add a return statement outside the `while`.

When you say

> If I put the "return balance" anywhere else it says that the
>   system.out.println is unreachable

You put the return statement right before a `System.out.println()` statement. When a method returns, it gives up on anything that might've happened after the `return` statement, basically making anything after it useless. The `return` statement must be the last statement in some execution branch of your method.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the compiler can't guarantee that the return statement will execute because it is within your loop.  It has to assume that `in.hasNext()` may return false and never hit that return.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the "Missing return statement" error because there is a possiblity that your `while` loop is never executed. This leads to the program reaching the end of the function without ever returning.

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
  if (command.equals("penny")) {
    balance = balance + 0.01;
    System.out.println("balance = " + balance);
  }
  return balance;
}
```

If we pretend `in` never has any lines then the program passes the `while` and therefore the `return` causing this issue. For your case you can probably just have a default return such as `return 0;` or however you'd like to handle the situation.