# Missing return statement inside a for loop

Tags: java, loops, return

I could find similar questions to this, but I could not find the answer that I expect to this particular case.

```
public int getIndex(){
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, I got a compilation error saying "Missing return statement". But, as per my knowledge, it is very clear that the code within the for loop will execute without any doubts due to the first time, x=0. So, there is no case not to execute the code inside the for loop for this particular case.
So, why do we need to declare an extra return statement outside the for loop also?.

Comment: Is this real code? you can change it to return 0. can you give a *real* example?

Comment: What is the use-case of this code?

Comment: Guys, it is clearly a theoretical question, he is asking why do we need to have a `return` outside of the `for` loop for it to work correctly, even though it will clearly never reach the other `return`.

Comment: Sounds like bad static analysis on the IDE's part. It should definitely be able to tell that it's not necessary. What IDE out curiosity?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the code *does* make sense. It's not particularly useful (functionally speaking) but it makes the question rather clear.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I was referring to the people trying to "fix" the code and ask for the use case of the code, the _use_ of the code does not matter, he wants to know for knowledge's sake, it does not mean it will necessarily be useful.  And a lot of people clearly understand what he meant, so I think the code was just fine.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no, that's the point. This is not a logical error. It's just bad code. Like plenty of bad code that gets posted here every day. If people didn't post bad code (or even logical errors) this site wouldn't need to exist. Furthermore, I wish my compiler could detect actual logical errors, but, alas, it doesn't.

Answer (score 10):

Unlike you, the compiler is unable to (or rather, does not *try* to) determine that the loop executes at least once.

The specific rules around this are given in [JLS 14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21). In particular:

> A basic for statement can complete normally iff at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The for statement is reachable, there is a condition expression, and the condition expression is not a constant expression (§15.28) with value true.
> - There is a reachable break statement that exits the for statement.
>
> The contained statement is reachable iff the for statement is reachable and the condition expression is not a constant expression whose value is false.

You don't have a constant condition expression, so, the compiler considers that such a for loop can complete normally, hence the statements after it are reachable.

[It would work](https://ideone.com/EpDSw6) without a further return statement if the `i < 5` were a constant expression, such as `true`.

```
public int getIndex(){
    for(int x = 0; true; x++) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

The compiler could determine that your original loop never completed normally, given far more complicated rules about reachability, but the practical use cases of this are so small that it would not justify the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

This is because JVM have no idea about conditional break you will use inside the loop. For example :

```
public static int getIndex(){
  for(int x=0; x<5;x++){
    if(x<5) continue;
    return x;
  }
  return 6;
}
```

Here it's clear that without a return outside the loop you could miss return statement inside loop

Comment: The JVM *does* have an idea, at a certain point. The compiler, on the other hand...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that your example isn't real, But you can change it to do-while without compilation errors:

```
public static int getIndex() {
    int x = 0;
    do {
        return x++;         
    } while (x < 5);
}
```

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca return is before loop executed so there's no need to add return after loop

Comment: Won't this never loop and always just return the starting value of `x`?  EDIT: Nevermind, I'm dumb I forgot his is the same way.

Answer (score 1):

in your function

**- This method must return a result of type int**

error generation

bcz

```
public static int getIndex(){
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            return x;
        }  
    }
```

not have specify return value out side function
Default return

```
public static int getIndex(){
        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            return x;
        }  
       return 0; <---------
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

These conditions are not understandable at compile time, whereas at runtime they are understood by JVM. But for the code to compile it requires a return statement outside the for-loop. So to get the code compiled, you must have a return statement theoretically.